# Does USB A or C connector have a higher current capacity for power delivery?

Tags: usb

Assuming constant voltage (5V) and that cable is irrelevant (it will be thick enough), which USB connector would have lower temperature rise, big old plain brick of USB A 1.1 or new but small USB C?

I want it to handle no more than 3 amps, but I want it to have as little temperature rise a possible. Just because of its massive dimensions I lean in favor of USB-A 1.1 but I see "USB-C power delivery" hyped everywhere and I wonder maybe USB-A 1.1 has some flaw other than its size that USB-C solves.

Comment: You can get USB-C cables rated for 5A, while the old USB charging spec for type A maxed out around 2A I believe.

Comment: If you check a few [USB-A connector's](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/filter/usb-dvi-hdmi-connectors/312?s=N4IgjCBcoEwBxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIALGHAMwUCsIAuoQA4AuUIAyuwE4BLAHYBzEAF9CYAJxxpiECkgYcBYmRAAGZm06Qe-YWPEmgA) contact current rating, you'll see that it's not more that 2 Amps. Regarding the temp rise, you can never guarantee a low temp rise in either socket but In a few USB wall-type chargers with type-A connector that I designed, at full load (i.e. 2.1A) the connectors' temperature was around 40-50°C which is enough to feel by touching.